# How to compare parts of flat files?

Tags: python

I have some simple data stored in series of text files.  Once line per record, but number and type of fields can vary per record.

The files contain *almost* the same data.

The exists an "ideal" data file to which these must be compared.  Some fields can vary, but some need to match.  I also need to now if any records are missing / added compared to the master.

What would be a good approach to take?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to compare the files programatically, or is a human doing the comparison and you just need a tool to help you highlight the differences between the two files?

Comment: Can't you just use `diff` or some side by side diffing tool?

Comment: Trying to compare programatically, not by hand.   Diff wont work, as large parts of the records can vary, and also it's not necessarily a pure string comparison.   For some numeric fields, "close" is OK.

Comment: Could you create a script that would run `diff` and pipe the results to your program?

Comment: You're going to have to parse this into some sort of data structure and go from there. Do you have an example of the data, or are you not looking for specifics on how to go about doing that?

Comment: Alex, yeah that is what i was thinking.   Records are between 3-5 fields, and there are only a few valid combination of fields.  Definitely looking for specifics.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the following to simply iterate over every combination of lines from file1 and file2.
I think the for, else construction works well here.

```
def comparefiles(file1, file2):
    for row in file1:
        for row in file2:
             #check all of your lines, break if condition is met
        else:
             #no matches
```

Comment: I know this is just a rough guideline but you may also want to check if *file2* contains additional rows that are not in *file1*.

Comment: This would certainly work, but is there a way to gather up statistic on "correctness" and not totally die if file2 is missing a record at the beginning?  (also keeping in mind i'd be looping through 20+ "file2"s)

Comment: The break doesn't totally die, it would only exit the the second for loop.  Basically, when you find the match to the line in file 1, the break would say ok I found my match, I no longer have to check file2.

Comment: You would invoke this function for each file2 that you are iterating through.  What you return from this function is dependent on your use, which you didn't detail here.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with unutbu, you should use difflib for that.

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, file1.read(), file2.read())
```

Comment: Looking at difflib docs, but it seems built for text.  In my case i have non-"string" text data too.   1.9 is "close enough" to 2.0, for instance.

Comment: @user489549: you could always do a second pass to sanitize the diff lines. This way, bulk of  logic to copare lines will be left to difflib and custom logic can be applied to changed lines. This way the sequencer can also match when multiple lines has been inserted lines appropriately

Comment: @user489549: In fact, it won't die if some lines were missing. It will show up in the diff.